# How can I link my Stack Overflow account to a different Google account?

Tags: support, login, accounts

I need to change the Google account that is linked to my Stack Overflow account. I have read that this can be done by adding a login to an account, and then removing the old one. I have tried multiple times to do this. See screenshots, and follow my numbered steps:

[image]

1. I clicked "my logins"
2. I clicked "add more logins"
3. I clicked "Add a login using Google"
4. I got redirected back to my Stack Overflow profile - every time

How can I fix it?

Comment: Add a different method temporarily, disconnect your google, then add in the other one.

Comment: What is a "method"? I don't understand.

Comment: Another login option, like local username/password or a different OAuth account (besides google). once that is attached, remove your old google account, and add your new google account.

Comment: I can't give up all my points with the other account. I need them merged, or etc. How can this be done?

Comment: You can request a merge, but it shouldn't be necessary in this case. Adding a second login method/account is a well-supported action.

Answer (score 8):

tl;dr: You need to log out of Google before adding the new account.

Answer as found on [webapps.stackexchange.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51263/how-do-i-log-into-stack-overflow-using-a-different-google-account-than-signed-in):

1. Log into Stack Overflow using your existing linked Google account
2. In a separate window, visit https://myaccount.google.com/ and log out of Google by clicking on your image in the upper right and selecting `Sign out of all accounts`
3. Now follow the steps you were trying on Stack Overflow (`My logins` / `Add more logins` / `Add a login using Google`) and you will be prompted to log into a Google account, and you can log into the one you are trying to link